# how to recover the beginning of week Monday

Tags: php, date

I have this line of code

```
$date=new \DateTime('now');
```

From that date, I need to recover date of the Monday at the beginning of the week.

For example when `$date=14_05_2014 19:12:20` (14 May 2014), I need a variable that has the value for the corresponding Monday: `$n=12_05_2014 08:00:00` (12 May 2014).

Comment: Please make your future question more readable (punctuation marks, new lines, etc...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fairly easy given the powerful date/time functions in PHP:

```
$now = new \DateTime('now');

# "1" means "Monday", you could improve this by detecting localized settings
$daysToMove = (int)($now->format('N')) - 1; // 

# How many days to subtract?
if ($daysToMove){
    $now->sub(new \DateInterval('P' . $daysToMove . 'D'));
}

echo "Start of the week: " . $now->format('Y-m-d');
```

Simple explanation:

1. you calculate current day of the week. This value can be in range `1..7`.
2. Since, Monday is `1`, subtract `1` from calculated number.
3. If resulting number of greater that `0` (meaning "today is not Monday"), create `DateInterval` and subtract it from current date.

You can find more about `DateTime` and `DateInterval` classes: [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.sub.php). Look for `Examples` section...

PHP `date()`: [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

PHP `DateTime` (OOP variant): [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

Comment: i will test him , can you explain me more this code and thank you

Comment: how can i import DataInterval ?  ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "DateInterval" from namespace

Comment: can you help again how can i inialise the date :$now->format('Y-m-d');   to 08:00:00 i mean date of Monday at 08:00:00

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if you read the date documentation instead? I mean, it not problem to me to help you but those are fundamentals of `date` functionality and every `PHP` dev should at least know how to find them...